# No podspec found for `react-native-beacons-manager` in `../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager`

Tags: react-native, beacon

Since the last "pod install", i get the error "No podspec found for `react-native-beacons-manager` in `../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager`" if i ran "pod install" and i dont know why. The library works until the last month. But now, i get the error.

I add the following in react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/app/static/fonts/'],
    dependencies: {
        'react-native-beacons-manager': {
            platforms: {
                android: null,
                ios: null,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

In the ios/Podfile i add the following:

```
  pod 'react-native-beacons-manager', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager'
```

In XCode under "Libraries" i add RNiBeacon.xcodeproj

I the following Versions:

- iOS 15.5
- NPM 8.3.1
- NodeJS 16.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Add a react-native-beacons-manager.podspec to node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager with the following code:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "react-native-beacons-manager"
  s.version      = "1.1.0"
  s.summary      = "React-Native library for detecting beacons (iOS and Android)"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager#readme"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT" }
  s.authors      = { "" => "" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
  s.source       = { :path => "." }
  s.source_files = "ios", "ios/**/*.{h,m}"

  s.dependency 'React'
end
```

Add in the Podfile the following line:
pod 'react-native-beacons-manager', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/react-native-beacons-manager.podspec'